# Enabling nXhtml only with HTML like file

Tags: emacs

I'm using emacs for most of my programming work. I've installed nXhtml just for using it with PHP and Django templates. The way in which I eneble nXhtml mode in my .emacs is:

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/nxhtml/autostart.el")
(setq mumamo-background-colors nil) 
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html$" . django-html-mumamo-mode)
```

Unfortunately mode is enabled all time from the very start of emacs in spite of a type of the file. Is there any way for enabling it only when needed, just for .html, .php files?
Thanks!

Comment: I also find this behaviour quite annoying. However, I don't have a vague idea how to change it. =/
nXhtml starts everywhere, and I can't make it enabled only on certain types of pages.